# Fade in and out an image constantly in Android app

Tags: android, animation, fadein, fadeout

I'm trying to make an image fade in and out constantly, but it just fade in and out one time.
How can I make it repeat constantly?
Here's the code:

```
Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
    fadeIn.setDuration(1000);

    Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
    fadeOut.setStartOffset(1000);
    fadeOut.setDuration(1000);

    AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(true);
    animation.addAnimation(fadeIn);
    animation.addAnimation(fadeOut);
    ImageView loading = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.loading);
    loading.startAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Animator, it's pretty easy :

```
Animator alphaAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(loading, View.ALPHA, 0f, 1f);
alphaAnimator.setDuration(1000);
alphaAnimator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
alphaAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
alphaAnimator.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should repeat your animation:

```
animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the method [setRepeatMode(int repeatMode)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setRepeatMode(int)) from `Animation` class.